# Template method inside a class

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-overloading, member

I have a class called `time` which has `day`, `month` and `year`.

I have a problem with returning the right value in my method, where it, depending on what we enter as a string `"s"` it should return an `int` value from one of those 3 fields.

So, for example, if I want to get days in my *date* I should call the function `d["day"]`.
My question is, Is there something wrong with my code here? And, what should I put instead of

```
int operator[] (string s) 
{
    if (s == "day" || s == "month" || s == "year") 
    {
        return ? ? ? ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should better use standard library [classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) for datetime logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the explanation, if I understood correctly, you need the following. You need to return appropriate member (i.e. either `day` or `month` or `year`) according to the string match. (Assuming that you have `mDay`, `mMonth`,  and `mYear` as `int` eger members in your `Date` class)

```
int operator[] (std::string const& s) 
{
    if (s == "day")   return mDay;
    if (s == "month") return mMonth;
    if (s == "year")  return mYear;
    // default return
    return -1;
}
```

or alternatively using a [`switch` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

```
// provide a enum for day-month-year
enum class DateType{ day, month, year};

int operator[] (DateType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case DateType::day:   return mDay;
    case DateType::month: return mMonth;
    case DateType::year:  return mYear;
    default:              return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this method also be put as a template? And how should that be implemented?

Comment: So, if I want to put the operator in a generic method.
It should look something like this:
template <string S>
int operator[] (string const& s){
if (S == s) return S;
}
or something like that

Answer (score 1):

A dimple way is to define the date as an array of three elements instead of declaring three separate data members.

In this case the operator can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

class MyDate
{
private:
    unsigned int date[3] = { 26, 12, 2019 };
public:
    unsigned int operator []( const std::string &s ) const
    {
        const char *date_names[] = { "day", "month", "year" };

        auto it = std::find( std::begin( date_names ), std::end( date_names ), s );         
        if (  it == std::end( date_names ) )
        {
            throw std::out_of_range( "Invalid index." );
        }
        else
        {
            return date[std::distance( std::begin( date_names ), it )];
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    MyDate date;

    std::cout << date["day"] << '.' << date["month"] << '.' << date["year"] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
26.12.2019
```

Otherwise you should use either if-else statements or a switch statement within the operator.